# Send email from static page hosted on GitHub Pages

Tags: html, forms, github-pages

I have hosted a single static HTML page using GitHub Pages. I need to add a "Send Feedback" feature to my static page where a user can type in his name, email, comments and click the SUBMIT button. This will send an email with the contents to my email address. Can this somehow work in a static HTML page on GitHub? Does GitHub Pages support this mailing feature?

I also want to know what features/plugins etc can GitHub Pages server support based on the underlying web server it uses?

Comment: Probably the only way would be to post to another hosted file (PHP or other technology on another server). You can probably look in Google Forms or something like that.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This cannot be done natively on GitHub pages.  You will need to use [some](http://getsimpleform.com/) [kind](http://www.wufoo.com/) [of](http://kontactr.com/) [form submission tool](http://blog.templatemonster.com/2010/07/08/free-contact-form-services/).

GitHub's [pages documentation](https://help.github.com/categories/20/articles) describes what you can and cannot do with the hosting, and what plugins it supports.

Answer (score 109):

Yes it can be done this way with the help of Formspree.

**Formspree**

http://formspree.io/

HTML forms
Just send your form to our URL and we'll forward it to your email. No PHP, Javascript or sign up required — perfect for static sites!You just need to open your text editor, and paste the following code:

```
<form action="http://formspree.io/you@email.com"><input type="email" name="_replyto"><textarea   name="body"></textarea><input type="submit" value="Send"></form>
```

That's it, your form already works! It will post the form onto an external domain, formspree.io, and send you an email with all the form content. No database. And you can just hit reply in your mailbox to continue the conversation with your visitor.

This tool was built by the guys from Brace, then open-sourced and hosted by Assembly.

> Setting it up is easy and free. Here's how:
>
> You don't even have to register.
>
> 1. Setup the HTML form
>
> Change your form's action-attribute to this and replace your@email.com
> with your own email.
>
> http://formspree.io/your@email.com
>
> 2. Submit the form and confirm your email address
>
> Go to your website and submit the form once. This will send you an
> email asking to confirm your email address, so that no one can start
> sending you spam from random websites.
>
> 3. All set, receive emails
>
> From now on, when someone submits that form, we'll forward you the
> data as email.

Comment: Question for you: what happens if you use the AJAX Post Request method instead of just using the action attribute on the form tag? Will that send an e-mail without taking the user to Formspree's Thank You page?

Comment: Although I haven't tried it. But there is way to that. You can use Formspree via AJAX. This even works cross-origin. The trick is to set the Accept header to application/json. If you're using jQuery this can be done like so:

$.ajax({
    url: "//formspree.io/you@email.com", 
    method: "POST",
    data: {message: "hello!"},
    dataType: "json"
});

Comment: A heads up: it appears the AJAX method can only be used for gold-paying customers.

Comment: AJAX is supported for free again. See my longer update here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58721654/866413

Comment: Doesn't this expose your email address to spammers?

Comment: formspree.io now (updated 4 months ago) encourages you to use a unique URL after you register and set up your email once there. In this way, you can then replace your email with a unique token at the "action" form, which is given by the formspree.io settings of your project. Details: https://help.formspree.io/hc/en-us/articles/360056076314

Answer (score 40):

Github pages doesn't support php and some of the other backend stuff you'd need for this.  A simple approach is to just create a google form which corresponds to your html form and use the action submit to that.  It is a bit trickier to do it with out a redirect but it can be done.

Here's how I did it:
https://github.com/toperkin/staticFormEmails/blob/master/README.md

Comment: My friend, that's called thinking outside of the box... What about security though? Those are plain HTML request

Comment: Great solution! Easy to implement and it comes out of the box with the possibility to analyse the answers.

Comment: GREAT ANWARE! It shows an example on how to do it without server

Comment: Great solution! It still works, for those reviewing post April 2022

Answer (score 26):

GitHub Pages doesn't offer/support anything like this, since it's just a static website hosting. It serves HTML files and assets, but doesn't run server side scripts.

A few months ago I run into the same problem and did some research. As others mentioned, an external form handler service is needed for this task. Fortunately, there are tons of them:

- [99inbound](https://www.99inbound.com/)
- [Basin](https://usebasin.com/)
- [elFormo](https://www.elformo.com/)
- [enformed.io](http://www.enformed.io/)
- [formspree.io](https://formspree.io/)
- [mailthis.to](https://mailthis.to/)
- [Pageclip](https://pageclip.co/)
- [SimpleForm](https://getsimpleform.com/)
- [Un-Static](https://un-static.com/)

I compared their features and limits based on their website, then I chose, tried out **Basin** and finally I stuck with it. It offers spam filter, captcha verification, Zapier integration; hides your email address in your form and it can send an email receipt to the one who submitted the form - all of this for free. It works like a charm on my website (hosted on GitHub Pages) behind my contact form.

**EDIT:** It offered unlimited submissions when I originally wrote this answer, but now a paid subscription is required for unlimited submissions and a redirect URL. Free tier now includes 100 submissions/month.

It's very easy to set up, the administration interface shows HTML snippets to copy-paste. Your form will look something like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://usebasin.com/f/123456xabcdef" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" required></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Some time ago I wrote a [blog post](https://juzraai.github.io/blog/2018/contact-form-using-basin/) about testing Basin with more details.

Answer (score 13):

Formspree founder here.

Formspree has changed a bit in the last few years. It's now supports AJAX for free, spam filtering, optional captcha verification, and several built-in plugins including Zapier.

The best way to get started is to create a form on the home page (https://formspree.io), or go to https://formspree.io/create. The old way of putting your email directly in the URL still works, but that exposes your email in the HTML, and requires an activation step. Creating a form in Formspree avoids the form activation step, and hides your email address.

There's lots of up-to-date information about Formspree's features and common issues at https://help.formspree.io/. The product continues to improve on a weekly basis. Come check it out!

Comment: Are forms set up with Formspree more likely to be filtered as spam compared to regular emails sent from an email client? Does formspree set all the available security headers like the SPF and DKIM stuff? (you can tell I don't know anything about email security protocols)

Comment: @V.Rubinetti oops missed this. Hope you've been well for the last 2 years. Yes Formspree sets DKIM and SPF headers, and we work hard to ensure our email notifications have excellent delivery stats. :D

Comment: Formspree no longer supports the email urls, largely due to browser changes to the "referer" field.

Answer (score 6):

This solution involves self-hosting the backend part on a virtual server, do not be scared of a little backend. Here is [my static GitLab page](https://just-code.team/) *without any third party form provider*.

I created an open source project that enables you to include a contact form into your GitHub, GitLab or any other static hosted websites. I find the answer, you cannot do it yourself, please use formspree not a good answer. While this is true that you currently cannot have a backend service hosted on GitHub and GitLab pages, you can forward your request using [cross origin resource sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to your own backend server.

The frontend part of my solution is available on GitLab [here](https://gitlab.com/just-code/just_contact_frontend). It uses jQuery Ajax to send the data with a HTTP post request using CORS to the backend. The PHP backend code is [here](https://gitlab.com/just-code/just_contact_backend). Because most people cannot be bothered with server installations, I included an [ansible playbook](https://gitlab.com/just-code/just_ansible) to do everything automatically.

The features include:

- google captcha
- form validation using jQuery Validation
- multiple file upload

So if you can be bothered to spend 30min to understand how to configure and deploy ansible playbooks, you can use my solutions. Cloud providers have very competitive prices. (OVH [vps starters](https://www.ovh.de/order/vps/?v=3#/vps/build?selection=%7E(range%7E%27Starter)) from 3,50eur/month, [netcup](https://www.netcup.de/vserver/vps.php) below 3eur/month). With the smallest VPS you can handle hundreds of concurrent form submissions for as many GitHub/ GitLab pages as you like. How much would it cost you at formspree?

The code for this solution is open source and hosted on GitLab for anyone to improve or fix any security issues. And because I think it sucks to charge for basic needs software, like a contact form, it will remain open source. Forever.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it can, there are many apps around the web that allows you to send emails from you static HTML with a couple of javascript lines.
Some of them are **mandrillapp**, sendgrid, among others, and the best of them, they are all free !

Comment: Really mandrill will do this? Is there a JavaScript API or something?

Answer (score 0):

I built https://www.formbackend.com for things like these. The only thing you need is to create a form-backend on the website and use the unique URL as the `action` in your `<form action="[FORMBACKEND_UNIQUE_URL]">`

The field you add to the form will be submitted to our backend, where you can either view them online - or you can set it up so you receive an email every time someone submits your form! :)

Answer (score 0):

No this is not supported by any static sites you will build. Yet there are a ton of services that can help you do this. Right now you just need a `static form` in your website but as time goes on you will want to do more things like:

- What users are doing on your site
- email them offers
- increase engagement and a lot more.

I am trying out a tool [Formester.com](https://www.formester.com) which will help you do all of this at an affordable price.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, You can't do via Github pages. You can achieve via a submission tool.

I found an article from [Medium.com](https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/how-to-host-static-react-website-with-contact-forms-for-free-e12fbdc2414b). In the article, the author mentioned the http://formspree.io/ as a submission tool. In this article author clearly mentioned the steps. I think this link is helpful for you.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you create/Use Sendgrid(or anything like that) a smtp api , and use axios to post a request for sending any mail.

Comment: This does not answer the question.