# Is there a way to send e-mail from github.io without external hosting?

Tags: php, email, github

I have a question about github pages. I have created there my site, and I want to add contact form so users can contact with me through this form, but as I can see in github.io is not possible publish or use .php files... So is there a way to send e-mail from my site contact form to my e-mail address?

P.S also I read [this one](http://imakewebthings.com/blog/github-pages-email/), and there was mentioned external hosting, but I don't have it, so for me it doesn't works...

Any ideas?

P.P.S sorry for bad English =(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email from static page hosted on GitHub Pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348223/send-email-from-static-page-hosted-on-github-pages)

Answer (score 6):

Yes it can be done this way with the help of formspee.

**Formspree**

http://formspree.io/

HTML forms
Just send your form to our URL and we'll forward it to your email. No PHP, Javascript or sign up required — perfect for static sites!You just need to open your text editor, and paste the following code:

```
<form action="http://formspree.io/you@email.com"><input type="email" name="_replyto"><textarea name="body"></textarea><input type="submit" value="Send"></form>
```

That's it, your form already works! It will post the form onto an external domain, formspree.io, and send you an email with all the form content. No database. And you can just hit reply in your mailbox to continue the conversation with your visitor.

This tool was built by the guys from Brace, then open-sourced and hosted by Assembly.

> Setting it up is easy and free. Here's how:
>
> You don't even have to register.
>
> 1. Setup the HTML form
>
> Change your form's action-attribute to this and replace your@email.com
>   with your own email.
>
> http://formspree.io/your@email.com
>
> 2. Submit the form and confirm your email address
>
> Go to your website and submit the form once. This will send you an
>   email asking to confirm your email address, so that no one can start
>   sending you spam from random websites.
>
> 3. All set, receive emails
>
> From now on, when someone submits that form, we'll forward you the
>   data as email.
>
> [1]: http://formspree.io/

Comment: I uses formspree on my github website and it works like charm!