# Make contact form for GitHub Page

Tags: github, github-pages

I have used github for hosting my website. My contact form is in html and php, but as github does not support php. How to make this form work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). As you note, GitHub does not support PHP for GitHub Pages; this isn't something we can help you with, since only GitHub can control what they support.

Comment: @ScottWeldon, is it a positive way to encourage @rebeca-p to use stackoverflow ? I don't think so. We are somewhere a customer support. We are here to help people, not to close the doors. I've removed `git` tag and I'm sure you can remove your nonconstructive comment as well as (I guess) your downvote.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks a lot!!!
Thanks @David   .I ask my apologizes, my question was a "open question" and no specific.In fact github is a static site.Can I use webhooks or anyone API or remote JS(using an external server) to send emails?Please, Let me know if there is a better way(clean) to integrate email to my web site.
Thanks again for your patient.
Rebeca

Comment: Hi Rebeca. Are you talking about contact form or is it a new question, specific to emails ?

Comment: Hello, yes , David, my contact form just is ready,no problem. This question is specific to integrate in my website, if possible, either an api or remote js to send email, considering github is for static site ,only .Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email from static page hosted on GitHub Pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348223/send-email-from-static-page-hosted-on-github-pages)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Github Pages only supports static sites and does not support server-side languages.

To make a form, you could you a third party service such as [kontactr](http://kontactr.com/) or [formspree](https://formspree.io/)

Comment: You can use https://formspree.io/ contact form service service.

Comment: Check out www.enformed.io. Has a couple of interesting options that formspree does not have( Like redirect out of the box, and a html email editor).

Comment: I saw that enformed is pretty straight forward but I am concerned about seciurity. Is there any concern regarding the TOKEN that is in plain view in the HTML file?