# Is it possible to link PHP code to "contact form" in github pages?

Tags: php, gmail, contact-form

There is a contact form in a webpage that is linked to gmail account via a PHP code. Is it possible to use github pages as a host for this webpage and receive feed backs?

Comment: Not possible. GitHub pages don't run PHP code AFAIK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email from static page hosted on GitHub Pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348223/send-email-from-static-page-hosted-on-github-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible as Github pages do not does not run any interpreter (be it PHP, Python or whatever). You can however use a third party API/service.

Also see these questions:

- (duplicate) [Send email from static page hosted on GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348223/send-email-from-static-page-hosted-on-github-pages)
- [How to send an email from
  JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)