# Integrating FormSpree into GitHub Jekyll markdown file

Tags: github, jekyll, contact-form, github-flavored-markdown

I am attempting to add a contact form to a GitHub Jekyll website. I have mostly been following advice from the most-liked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348223/send-email-from-static-page-hosted-on-github-pages), from a YouTube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykeZisJ64WI), and from the [FormSpree site](https://formspree.io/).

In my attempt to keep the website design consistent, one major difference compared to these tutorials is probably that I am adding the FormSpree contact form to a markdown file, which is [here](https://github.com/testMDRS/testMDRS.github.io/blob/master/sponsors.md). As you can see in this markdown file, I tried creating the form twice (once with bare-bone suggestions and once with more bells and whistles).

I am almost certain the form is not looking as expected (which in the YouTube tutorial I was following would look more like [this](https://prateepgedupudi.github.io/contact/)) because I am not using a .html file. However, when I tried to convert my page to .html instead of .md it rendered the contact form page looking visually/aesthetically inconsistent with the rest of the webpage tabs. As a result, I am hoping to maintain the .md format with the same current YAML metadata.

My question is: Is it possible to add a FormSpree contact form to GitHub Jekyll pages directly inside a Markdown (.md) file and, if so, what alterations would I need to make to accomplish this? Thank you for sharing any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using html chunks in md files can seem quite tricky.

In your particular case, as you're including raw html, you can use [nomarkdown extension](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#extensions) tag.

Just try :

```
{::nomarkdown}
<form action="http://formspree.io/moqeoggo method="POST">
  <input type="email" name="_replyto">
  <textarea   name="body"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>


{:/nomarkdown}
```