# Integrating FormSpree into GitHub Jekyll (Returns message: Form should post)

Tags: github, error-handling, jekyll, contact-form

I am hoping to add a contact form to a GitHub Jekyll website. I have mostly been following advice from the most-liked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348223/send-email-from-static-page-hosted-on-github-pages), from a YouTube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykeZisJ64WI), and from the [FormSpree site](https://formspree.io/).

I created a FormSpree account, verified my e-mail address, and created a form (obtained an ID). Then, I tried to add a contact form into my GitHub Jekyll website, the code of which can be seen [here](https://github.com/mdrs227/mdrs227.github.io/blob/master/contact.md). After that, I went to the corresponding site of that code ([here](https://mdrs227.github.io/contact/)) and sent a test form submission. In the e-mail address field, I tried both the e-mail address connected to FormSpree and an alternative email address.

Either way, upon submitting the "Send" button at the bottom of the page, the page refreshed with an error message: "Form should POST - Make sure your form has the `method=POST` attribute". I also did not receive the tested message in my email connected to FormSpree. I tried to research this error but see no solutions. As can be seen in the code ([here](https://mdrs227.github.io/contact/)), I believe I *do* set a `method=POST` attribute.

I am unsure how to proceed given my inability to effectively interpret the error message. Any advice on how to render this type of contact form successful, especially given this error message, would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Your link to "https://mdrs227.github.io/contact/" is giving a 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your HTML:

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/email@gmail.com method="POST" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
```

Your action is missing a closing double-quote (`"`) which leads to a false interpretation of your `action` attribute as `"https://formspree.io/email@gmail.com method="` and your actual method as an invalid attribute `post"`.

Should be fixed by replacing the above line with

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/email@gmail.com" method="POST" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
```

Doing so in your pages source code, I was able to submit the form and landed on FormSpree landing page indicating, that your form needs to be activated.